# eclipse subversion "Launch configuration cynosure references non-existing project cynosureBeta."

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a subversion repository that I checked out using the Subversive Eclipse plug-in.

Whenever I attempt to run the project, an error appears: "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches".

Then, I created a run configuration for a Java application with project `cynosureBeta` and main class `cynosureBeta/trunk/src/cynosure/beta/CynosureMain.java`. Eclipse finds the project when I manually type it in, but when I search for the project using the "Browse..." button, the project doesn't appear!

With the project name/main class manually typed in, pressing the run button returns a window saying "Launch configuration cynosure references non-existing project cynosureBeta".

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?! Thank you in advance.